# Android AchartEngine XLable and bar issue

Tags: android, achartengine

Using achartengine i am displaying graphs, but issue with bars.

When i add normal 5-10 data at x-axis its displayed good graphs as below image.
Bar spacing displayed normal.

[image]

But when i add full data between 20-25 at x-axis its not display proper bar graphs as below image. Bar spacing not displayed. Joint all the bars together.

[image]

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What do you want to do? Increase spacing or decrease bar width?

Comment: i want increase spacing between bars.

Answer (score 1):

```
renderer.setBarWidth(30);
renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
```

Comment: than increse barspacing